# Spring Security: How to pass oauth2 access token in request headers

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

On successful login to my spring security application configured with Oauth2, I received a response with Oauth2 token.

For the subsequent request I passed Oauth2 `access_token` in **URI Query Parameter** like this

```
http://localhost:8090/myapplication/users/user?access_token=4c520795-eb07-4c2d-a91b-474c85fb481e
```

It is working fine.

But instead of passing token in  URI to make it more secure I wanted to send token in request headers.How to do this?

Comment: How do you call the link?

Comment: I didn't get you can you please explain?

Answer (score 4):

Use the usual HTTP Authorization header:

```
Authorization: Bearer <your-token-here>
```

For example

```
Authorization: Bearer 4c520795-eb07-4c2d-a91b-474c85fb481e
```